# forgot password link takes me to home page in .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I Enabled Forgot password in my mvc project and the link has been sent to email but when i click the link it takes me to home page not to password reset page

note : the url is loclalhost:1157/Account/Resetpassword?userid="user id was in link"&code="some code was in link"

but the view is home page

Comment: "Resetpassword" does not look like any Webpage I am aware of. Should that page not end on .aspx or soemthing like that?

Comment: no i am using mvc with razor views not asp

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to asses your routing without seeing what your project looks like and if an ActionResult is setup for the Resetpassword view. I assume you are using razor view and not aspx?

What I can do is give you the following example of how I accomplish specific site access via a link in email.

We generate some html and send the email via smtp or wichever method you are using. The link to click on is a simple anchor tag with the href containing the url and query string. example:

email text: Please click HERE to access passwordReset. 
The anchor html: `<a href="https://www.testSite.com/PasswordReset/AuthEmailClick?AutKn=07531a9d-84cb-4282-9387-1373fe9837be"`

What is happening above is that we generate a token that stores the users information instead of including the actual user info. If you observe the above url, "PasswordReset" is the controllerName, "AuthEmailClick" is the ActionResult that will determine to which view the user is directed.

In your project you need to have a "PasswordReset" controller as in the above example, inside this controller, you need an ActionResult called "AuthEmailClick" as in the above example. Code:

```
public ActionResult AuthAprEm(string AutKn)
    {
        //The token in the email is stored in database
        var authDetails = 
            GenMethods.ExecuteStoredProc("RedeemAuthToken", 
            new List<string> { "Token" }, 
            new List<object> { AutKn }, 
            "SQL CONNECTION STRING");

        //If the token is invalid, return to relevant view for user to see
        if (authDetails.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("TokenUsed", "Home", new { });
        }
        else
        {
            //GET DESIRED INFORMATION FROM DATABASE QUERY, THEN REDIRECT TO DESIRED VIEW
            var username = authDetails.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
            var userPwd = authDetails.Rows[0]["UserPassword"].ToString();
            if (username.ToLower().Contains("tmp_") && userPwd.ToLower().Contains("tmp_"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("TempCredWarn", "Home", new { });
            }
            var authRsp1 = WebAuth.UserAuth(username, userPwd, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbPlaceHolder"].ConnectionString.Replace("{PlcHold}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostDb"]));
            authRsp1.Staib = true;
            return RedirectToAction("CreateNewSession", authRsp1);
        }
    }
```

So in the above example there is an ActionResult that will be invoked when the user clicks the link in the email. In this actionResult you can follow whichever logic you prefer. The important apsect is the RedirectToAction which you will ultimately include your "resetPassword" action name, which will be executed and return the correct view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using mvc with individual authentication and razor views

Comment: this is the url
http://localhost:1157/Account/ResetPassword?userId=9cc6c98f-0993-4f13-a6b6-a1c3b487ceb7&code=u2JI7%2F%2BwmWyuNvoyoCjce9TK1%2FoI%2Fh8fNAVbUaAAXjPWjejtblQvz1uzI%2B30hxVxTNTRRvl8lOJRFx9toFa%2Ba9M3asu51tq3p7px1Nq0jlnrp5ZXBlkhLLvSGDJK%2B40x77iVkTkHORymlsmm7dZDImGnW2qHPDwCQSAOmm3YdvP3wUuH2Abi2nxBBqi3eBfcj%2Fu1y8ZGYt%2FJGy%2BWQqyP%2Fw%3D%3D

and the view is home page

Comment: Did you try the above? Your userId is a GUID, is the query string parameter types matching the types you are sending I.E string instead of int?